# How can I read a files which has variables in it with jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy

Can I read a file and dynamically form parameters in Jenkins? Var1 should be a parameter in a Jenkins job and should populate val1 as its value and can I edit that value which should update the file in turn?

Comment: File content: var1=val1, var2=val2, vsr3=val3... var20=val20

Answer (score 0):

Use powershell plugin and then get-content